# Bottom "toolbar" is not there; cannot make new material because of it,

Tags: node-editor, interface

I'm quite new to Blender and I want to make a new material using the Texture Node Editor. However, upon opening the Editor, everything is greyed out. Everything. I've tried looking online and a lot say that the toolbar across the bottom of the screen would have "New" or something similar, but my toolbar is completely gone. It looks like this, but Add > Input has everything greyed out. I'm not sure what to do and I would really appreciate help!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to go in the shader editor to create a new material, not in the the texture node editor.
[image]

However, if you want to edit a texture, you need first to add one in the texture properties. This will enable the check-button "Use nodes" in the texture node editor.
These textures are not a material, but can be used when sculpting or painting your material. They can also be used by certain modifiers.

[image]

You need to set the texture type to "brush" and check "use nodes" :

[image]